# MATLAB: How can I plot a mesh with variable edge/vertex colors?

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh

**Background**: I am solving Maxwell's equations using 2-D FD methods. In these methods, it is best to define the E-fields on cell edges and H-fields on cell centres.

Now, let's say I have a 4x4 mesh with 16 cells, 20 vertical edges, and 20 horizontal edges.

I have 16 values of H stored in a matrix. This can be plotted in pcolor with no issues.

However, I also have 20 values for the E-field stored on the vertical edges stored in a 4x5 matrix, and 20 values for the E-field on the horizontal edges stored in a 5x4 matrix.

**The Problem**: I want to plot a figure which shows the mesh where the *lines of the mesh are colored according to the E-field value*.

I could cobble together a way to do this by calculating the node positions and line distances and plotting each line in a for loop, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

**Minimal Example**: Someone asked for a minimal example so here it is, but it's not really much:

```
Ev = randi([0 1], 5,4); %vertical edges
Eh = randi([0 1], 4,5); %horizontal edges
```

How do I plot the vertical edges (Ev) and horizontal edges (Eh) on a mesh (assuming the length of each line is a unit length)? I want to color each line segment so that it is black if it is 0 and white if it is 1.

Cheers

Comment: minimal example etc....